# Is gidazepam considered legal in Ukraine?

Tags: medical, ukraine

I've checked the table of illegal drugs, and it seems like every other benzodiazepine is in there. But for some reason gidazepam is not. So is it considered legal (because I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in Ukraine, it is legal for doctors to prescribe it, for pharmacies to sell it if prescribed, and for patients to buy it. It is [registered with the State Register of Medicines of Ukraine](http://www.drlz.com.ua/ibp/ddsite.nsf/all/shlist?opendocument&query=%C3%B2%C4%C0%C7%C5%CF%C0%CC). I’ve seen published cases where the facts mention prescriptions and sales in 2020. It is also frequently supplied through public procurement (as [*Hydazepam*](https://prozorro.gov.ua/en/tender/search/?query=hydazepam) or [*Gidazepam*](https://prozorro.gov.ua/en/tender/search/?query=Gidazepam)).

As you already noticed, hydazepam is not on the effective [list of narcotics, psychotropic substances, and precursors by the Cabinet of Ministers of Ukraine](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/770-2000-%D0%BF#Text). I’ve even encountered [a recent court decision](https://reyestr.court.gov.ua/Review/92242310) citing an expert report from the end of 2019 stating that it doesn’t belong to them under the list which was effective then.

In 2019, [a procedure](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0655-19#Text) was adopted for determining analogous substances, which reproduce the psychoactive effects of the drugs from the above-mentioned list. But no list of such analogous substances has been published yet. According to the effective procedure, the list must be published at [the website of CMHMDAMH](https://cmhmda.org.ua/).

Answer (score 0):

Gidazepam is a low potency benzodiazepine orginally and presently produced in Russia and a few other CIS countries.  It is only available by prescription and is the drug primarily used for anxiety in CIS countries.  It is the only benzo that can be prescribed in those countries unless a patient is admitted to a hosptital. It is generally not available in other countries.

Comment: So, is that a yes or a no?

Comment: This does not answer the question.